# Printing with cmyk and greyscale same document

Tags: print-design, cmyk, tiff

I have a book being professionally printed which has cmyk images and black and white images (illustrations) which are saved as 20% dot gain tiffs. Would there be any problems printing this from the printers since there's two different colour profiles?

Answer (score 2):

No problems.

Greyscale is merely the black plate, or K in CMYK. If there is no other color information for a particular image, then only the black plate will be burned into the plate.

It's really no different than printing black type in a CMYK piece.... just the black plate.

You may actually get better image results by using a [rich black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_black) rather than greyscale. But that ultimately depends on what you wish to achieve with the images.

Answer (score 0):

Using different profiles in your images will not matter when going to press. The RIP software should be able to honor different source profiles and convert all profiles to the correct destination/output profile.